# Nontrivial periodic solutions of second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

We consider the ODE
$$x''(t)+x^3(t)=0.$$
Clearly, $x\equiv 0$ is a solution. But also, numerically solving this ODE shows that nontrivial periodic solutions exist, too. I am interested in proving the statement that the above ODE has a nontrivial periodic (say, $2\pi$ periodic) solution. How does one go about proving such a statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x'(t)=p(t)$, then the quantity $H$ is a constant of motion

$$
H=\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4}
$$

As we can verify

$$
\frac{dH}{dt}=pp'+x^3x'=x''x'+x^3x'=x'(x''+x^3)=0
$$

The term in $( ...)$ vanishes by virtue of the differential equation. The phase portrait is given by the **closed curves** $\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4}=\text{const}$, so the motion is periodic.

By the way, your equation has an 'exact' solution. Since $H$ is constant, we can write

$$
p^2=2H-x^4/2 \\
x'= \pm\sqrt{2H-x^4/2}
$$

This can be integrated to find $t(x)$

$$
t(x)=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2H-x^4/2}}
$$

Which is an elliptic integral. Finally, *in principle*, $t (x)$can be inverted to find $x(t)$.